# Is there a way to remove the Title bar on Firefox ubuntu:

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

It makes my view very restricted in comparison with chrome. Here is a comparison between firefox [comparison image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v9Cr.png)
(left) and chrome (right):

Comment: Does the "Title bar" checkbox in "Customize toolbars" menu not work anymore?

Answer (score 6):

In Firefox, Right click on the top bar and select *Customise Toolbar...*
A the bottom of the screen in the left hand corner you will see a checkbox for *Title Bar*. Make sure that is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work anymore starting from Firefox 113.0.1.

Comment: still there in 1.13.03

Comment: Still working for me.. this should be the answer imo

Answer (score 4):

Right-click the toolbar on firefox and select **Customize Toolbar**. Then uncheck the **Title Bar** checkbox on bottom left.
[image]

Comment: Doesn't work anymore

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on but after an update I didn't have this "Title Bar" option at the bottom, weird thing is that after restarting Firefox the option re-appeared and I was able to uncheck it. So if this option doesn't show for you, try restarting the browser.